# iOS - Search Display Controller not populating from view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" with a table view in a TableViewController.

I am trying to do a search so that when a user enters text into the search box, an ajax request goes out and does the search and returns the data. This is working just fine but for some reason, the Search Display Controller table is never populated.

The Search Display Controller delegate is set to the view controller in the storyboard and all the other connections seam fine based off the tutorials I have been trying to use but I never get any results in the search results table.

When I populate the initial table with data and then click on the search box (so the keyboard and everything show up) I can see the original table in the background grayed out. But as soon as I start typing, it all goes away and a blank table is shown.

My numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath sometimes get called but never if there is no data in the base table (only if I pre-populate the base table). But even when these are called from what seams like inside the Search Display Controller and return the correct values, the table always stays empty.

My view controller code is:

```
#import "SearchController.h"

static const NSString * LOG_KEY = @"SearchController";

@interface SearchController ()

@end

@implementation SearchController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchLocations = [SearchLocations getInstance];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //doesn't seam to be working
    //[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/* Data source table */
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"rows in table: %u", [self.searchLocations.locations count]);
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.searchLocations.locations count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@ new cell", LOG_KEY);
    SearchLocationCell * cell = (SearchLocationCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"searchLocationCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SearchLocationCell alloc] init];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = [self.searchLocations getLocationValue:@"name" forIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

/* Search bar methods */
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSLog(@"%@ should reload table for string: %@", LOG_KEY, searchString);
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"%@ didLoadSearchResultsTableView", LOG_KEY);
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    //we need at least 3 chars to search
    if ([searchText length] > 2)
    {
        [self.searchLocations getSearchResultsForString:searchText isFullSearchTerm:NO withCallback:self];
    }
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
}

/* SearchProtocol methods */
- (void)resultsLoaded
{
    NSLog(@"%@ resultsLoaded", LOG_KEY);
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchError
{
    NSLog(@"%@ searchError", LOG_KEY);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setSearchBar:nil];
    [self setSearchBar:nil];
    [self setSearchBar:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

What am I missing to populate the Search Display Controller table?

Comment: do u reload when u get data from webservice ?

[searchbarcontroller.tableview reloadData];

Comment: @yunas I don't have any variable or reference to searchBarController.tableView. Where would this be stored?